# C# WPF. Перенос текста на другие строчки в ячейке таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть такая ссылка по моему вопросу: [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn(v=vs.95).aspx) (свойство ElementStyle). Всё работает, как нужно.

Как теперь сделать так, чтобы во всех колонках DataGrid можно было применить перенос текста на другие строчки? Можно вручную для каждой колонки прописать, но это долго и занимает много кода. Если через стили делать, то я не знаю, как получить доступ к DataGridTextColumn, а после получить доступ к ElementStyle.

Пробовал у DataGrid написать такой код, ничего не получилось:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: А если прописать в стиле `TargetType="DataGridTextColumn"`?

Comment: `<DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>`

Comment: @АндрейNOP если написать это в стиле, то мне нужно задать какое-то значение свойства Value. Много текста писать не буду, вот сделал скриншот, как я делаю. Не уверен, что я правильно делаю. https://ibb.co/g00iCx

Comment: Ну я имел ввиду, что вот как у вас есть оставить, только targetType заменить. Это остается: `<Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>`

Comment: @Alias Попробовал ваш вариант, во время запуска приложения возникает это в VS: https://ibb.co/kBmUkH .

Comment: @Cuurjol, а у вас все столбцы текстовые? Или могут быть также DataGridCheckBoxColumn, DataGridComboBoxColumn или другие?

Comment: @АндрейNOP У `TargetType="DataGridTextColumn"` нет свойства `TextWrapping`, а вот `ElementStyle` есть. Вот я как снова сделал: https://ibb.co/bGnwXx

Comment: @АндрейNOP вот для конкретной таблицы да, все колонки я использую только текстовые. Вот код для конкретной DataGrid, который я использую: https://ibb.co/hc0YCx

Comment: Хм, да, DataGridTextColumn не является наследником FrameworkElement, поэтому не имеет свойства Style и, соответственно, стиль это не вынести отдельно... Остается действовать только как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37110972/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вроде бы как получилось по вашей ссылке. Ещё остался вопрос один: скажите, пожалуйста, я вот увидел это — `<UserControl.Resources>`. Правильно ли я понимаю, что вместо UserControl я должен конкретный Control указывать? Например, для Window это Window, для DataGrid это DataGrid и так далее. Неоднократно это видел здесь в ответах, так и никогда не понимал, зачем они пишут UserControl.

Comment: Да, это тот контрол, в котором вы эти ресурсы размещаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671836/how-get-a-wpf-datagrid-with-cells-that-wrap-text-instead-of-truncating-it/37110972#37110972) ссылке я попробовал сделать также для своего проекта. Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На всякий случай оставлю свой XAML-код:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CatalogDataGrid" Margin="0,5,0,0">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="WrapText">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Название" Width="50" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrapText}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Описание" Width="300" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrapText}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

С самого начала я думал, что как-то можно в `<Window.Resources>` написать стиль для всех существующих контролов DataGrid в окне, чтобы у DataGrid в колонках типа `DataGridTextColumn` текст переносился на другую строчку.

Но скорее всего в `<Window.Resources>` это сделать невозможно, поэтому для каждой отдельной DataGrid придётся добавлять тег `<DataGrid.Resources>`. На сегодняшний день это пока что лучшее решение моего вопроса.

Comment: Последний абзац сформулирован неправильно. Тем кто внимательно читал вопрос будет понятно что вы имеете ввиду, хотя.

Comment: Почему это невозможно в `<Window.Resources>`? Должно нормально же работать

Comment: Но вот от установки `ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrapText}"` для всех DataGridTextColumn не уйти никак, к сожалению, т.к. DataGridTextColumn не является наследником FrameworkElement и стиль для него не переопределить